# classify a value between to vectors and interpolate then R

Tags: interpolation, intervals

I've got a large dataframe in which there are many values (df1)
In Addition I've got a secound dataframe (df2) like a timeseries but converted to df.

I now want to take every measurement of df2 and classify it between two columns of df1.

df1 Looks like this basically:

```
     km X0.5MNQ    MNQ X0.5MQ      a X0.75MQ      b     MQ      c   X2MQ   X3MQ      d
1  1  106.64 107.18 107.53 107.79  108.02 108.23 108.44 109.16 109.79 110.87 111.61
2  2  106.64 107.18 107.53 107.79  108.02 108.23 108.44 109.16 109.79 110.87 111.61
3  3  106.63 107.18 107.53 107.78  108.01 108.23 108.43 109.15 109.78 110.86 111.60
4  4  106.63 107.17 107.52 107.77  108.00 108.21 108.41 109.13 109.76 110.83 111.57
5  5  106.63 107.17 107.51 107.76  107.99 108.20 108.41 109.12 109.74 110.81 111.55
```

df2 Looks like this:

```
          Date Pegelstand      MKZ Pegel Pegelkm  MKZkm
1   1960-01-01    109.696 50491952 Pirna       2      4
2   1960-01-02    109.596 50491952 Pirna       2      4 
3   1960-01-03    109.616 50491952 Pirna       2      4
4   1960-01-04    109.596 50491952 Pirna       2      4
5   1960-01-05    109.606 50491952 Pirna       2      4
6   1960-01-06    109.756 50491952 Pirna       2      4
7   1960-01-07    109.846 50491952 Pirna       2      4
```

I started with some code but I'm missing something so I can not go on with it.

```
workspace`<-...
files<-list.files(workspace,"csv", recursive = T)
data<-list()
  for (i in 1:length(files)){
    data[[i]]<-read.csv(paste(workspace,files[i],sep="/"), header = T, sep = ",")
    data[[i]]$Date<-as.Date(data[[i]]$Date)
    names(data[[i]])<-c("Date", "Pegelstand", "MKZ", "Pegel", "Pegelkm", "MKZkm")
  }
  #Zuordnung der Elbekilometer 
  for (i in 1:length(files)){
    ganglinie<-length(data[[i]]$Pegelstand)
    pegelkm<-mean(data[[i]]$Pegelkm)
    zeile_pegelkm<-which(fix$km==pegelkm) #Zeile in Fixierung mit Pegelwerten
    for (j in 1:ganglinie) {

     }
  }
```

In the first loop i define a list (data[[i]]) with all of my df2 timeseries but converted to dataframe format. Further I search for the row ind df1 which fits to my df2$Pegelkm (df1$km = df2$pegelkm).

Thats the reference row on which I want to find my two columns where measurement after measurement from df2 fits in. This shall happen in step 2. therefore I need a secound loop I guess.

When I know where my measurement fits in, I have to interpolate it depending on the values of the chosen columns from loop 2 in row df1$km = df2$MKZkm.

My main problem is to find the columns where the value fits in. Is there any simple solution?

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you have no problems in selecting a matching row in df1? Then, you can only fill a simple list or array with all column-values for this row. As next step you can check boundaries (first and last entry in this list) and search for nearest entry.

But I'm not sure, how you like to interpolate?! I interpret your values as y-values and miss the corresponding x-values.